# Member "name" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in string storage ref

Tags: solidity, remix, addresses, mapping, struct

I have code like this and I want to set my name, surname and age in my struct so I want to set them and get them using with my functions

here's my code :

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract NewHello{
    address owner;
    
    constructor()public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    modifier onlyOwner (){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    
    struct user{
        string name;
        string surname;
        uint age;
    }
    
    user[] new_user;
    mapping(address => string) public users; // contains a name for every address
    
    function updateUser(address _address, string memory name,string memory surname,uint age) public onlyOwner {
        user memory new_user = user(name,surname,age);
        users[_address] = user(name,surname,age);
        
    }
    function getUser(address _address) public view returns(string memory name ,string memory surname,uint age) {
        //if(users[_address].age == 0) throw;
        return (users[_address].name,users[_address].surname,users[_address].age); 
    }
}
```

I get 2 errors first one is :

```
TypeError: Type struct NewHello.user memory is 
not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage ref. 
users[_address] = user(name,surname,age);
                  ^--------------------^

TypeError: Member "name" not found 
or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in string storage ref.
```

anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Is not it simpler to use a mapping like this: `mapping(address => user) public users` ?

Comment: what should I do can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mapping like:

```
mapping(address => user) public users
```

Each address will have a user. You can improve that if you use [msg.sender](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) instead of address (function parameter), because you don't need to provide the address, and each user can change his data and see it (you need to remove the `onlyOwner` modifier in that case).

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract NewHello{ 

    address owner;

    constructor()public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner (){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    struct user{
        string name;
        string surname;
        uint age;
    }
    mapping(address => user) public users; // contains a user for every address

    function updateUser(address _address, string memory name, string memory surname, uint age) public onlyOwner {
        users[_address] = user(name, surname, age);
    }

    function getUser(address _address) public view returns(string memory name, string memory surname, uint age) {
         //if(users[_address].age == 0) throw;
        return (users[_address].name, users[_address].surname, users[_address].age);        
    }
}
```